# Execute command inside django

Tags: django, shell, python-2.7

I've been working with the PaaS service AppFog and I was able to get my Django up and running, but the problem is that my application uses static files and this are not working because it needs to execute the **collectstatic** command in shell.

I've been reading about it on the internet but I wasn't able to find a proper solution. Should I make a shell file and execute it? How?

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute **collectstatic** with the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This is called an administrative management command.  You can find out more about these and implementing them yourself by reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/.

Comment: The problem is I do not have shell access, so I can't execute it this way unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, that's an entirely different problem then.  If you can execute a shell file (as  you mentioned in your original post) you could put the above command in a shell script and execute it that way.  It ends up being the same thing.  If that doesn't work I'm sure we can figure another solution.

Comment: I can't execute it directly since I don't have a direct access to the server. I need to find a way that when Django's manage.py gets executed collectstatic gets executed as well. I appreciate your time.

Comment: As I thought about this last night and actually looked into AppFog some I had the thought that perhaps using some third party hosting option for the static files might be the best option. This morning I looked at a couple of sites that use AppFog and it appears that's exactly what they are doing. To pull this off you could run the command I provided locally and then push the resulting directory to Amazon S3 or something like that. Is that feasible for you?

Comment: I guess that is the best way to solve if for now. Thank you, @zzzirk!